# How can i change the language of an react-date-range DefinedRange?

Tags: reactjs, react-daterange-picker

**I've created a project that use a react-date-range component and i need to change the default language to PT.**

**DateRangePicker is in Portuguese but the DefinedRange in English and i need it in PT.**

At this moment I've tried:
`import pt from 'date-fns/locale/pt';` and

```
<DateRangePicker
  locale={pt}
  onChange={item => setRange([item.selection])}
  editableDateInputs={true}
  moveRangeOnFirstSelection={false}
  ranges={range}
  months={1}
  direction="horizontal"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

import { ptBR } from 'date-fns/locale'

locale={ptBR}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).